# Java JVM meta space allocated a lot but used little

Tags: java, garbage-collection

any idea why meta Sapce allocated a lot but used vevy little?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The size of metaspace is controlled by the JVM according to metaspace usage, and within the constraints of certain tuning parameters that are set via command line options ... or defaults.

- The `-XX:MetaspaceSize` option gives the initial size of metaspace.  The default is platform specific.
- The `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` option gives an upper limit for the size.  The JVM won't go beyond that limit.  The default for this is "unlimited".
- The `-XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio` and `-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio` control the JVM's resizing of metaspace following a GC run.  Basically, the JVM tries to keep the free space to used space ratio within the specified range ... by increasing or decreasing the size.

So to answer your question:

> Java JVM meta space allocated a lot but used less.

It will be a reflection of either how big the metaspace was to start with (determined by `-XX:MetaspaceSize` or its default value) and what the actual peak and recent metaspace usage patterns have been.

I haven't seen anything explicit about this, but metaspace resizing probably behaves like normal Java heap resizing.  The JVM only reduces the size of the metaspace only after a major garbage collection and does it "cautiously".  (If metaspace is reduced too much or too soon, that is liable to trigger a major garbage collection.)

However, there is no need to worry about this.  If the metaspace is underused, the unused portions should not (in the long term) tie down physical RAM pages.  The OS's virtual memory system should write out the page content to disk (if the pages are dirty) and then reallocate the RAM pages to something else.  Normal virtual memory stuff.

Comment: I could not understand 'what the actual peak and recent metaspace usage patterns have been.'   since everytime ,java service is restarted, it's started with a very high mem allocation.by default, it should be just 20MB.how come it jumps to 1.2GB

Comment: Read the entire sentence: *"It will be a reflection of either how big the metaspace was to start with (determined by -XX:MetaspaceSize or its default value) and what the actual peak and recent metaspace usage patterns have been."*.  And then read the next paragraph.  Then think how they relate.

Comment: thank you. are you saying the JVM will log recent metaspace usage pattern somewhere? so the jvm would use it when restarted.is there is any way to reset this?or remove the logs.

Comment: You can can also use `-XX:PrintCommandLineFlags` to see what the real initial values of all of the flags are.  Do that and add them to the question.

Comment: No.  I am saying that the JVM sets the initial metaspace size to whatever the default is.  Then it adjusts it according to actual usage.  But adjustments only happen *either* when metaspace fills *or* **slowly** if the metaspace is too large.  I also said: don't worry about it because it actually makes little difference.

Comment: Using `-XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy` might also tell you something interesting about the metaspace sizing decisions.